# How can I override a constant in an imported Python module?

Tags: python, module, python-import

In my application I am using module within the package `example` called `examplemod`.

**My app:**

```
from example import examplemod
examplemod.do_stuff()
```

It imports another module within `example` like so.

**examplemod.py:**

```
from example import config
# uses config
# then does stuff
```

`config` uses a constant.

**config.py:**

```
CONSTANT = "Unfortunate value"
```

I'd like to override this constant when I'm using `examplemod` in my application (setting it to `CONSTANT = "Better value"`) and I'd prefer not to modify the underlying module so I don't have to maintain my own package. How can I do this?

Comment: I could be wrong but I think you can just assign a value to the variable once it has been imported.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers. They pointed me in the right direction though none of them worked as written. I ended up doing the following:

```
import example.config
example.config.CONSTANT = "Better value"

from example import examplemod
examplemod.do_stuff()
# desired result!
```

*(Also, I'm submitting a patch to the module maintainer to make CONSTANT a configurable option so I don't have to do this but need to install the stock module in the mean time.)*

Answer (score 32):

Yes, but it'll only work as expected with fully qualified access paths to modules:

```
import example
example.examplemod.config.CONSTANT = "Better value"
example.examplemod.do_stuff()
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning that if the examplemod module imported CONSTANT directly into its symbol table with the `from config import CONSTANT` syntax, you'd need to do `example.examplemod.CONSTANT = "Better value"`, since examplemod would then have its own reference to CONSTANT. The form that you're using replaces config.CONSTANT, which works in the case that the examplemod module is using `from examplemod import config; config.CONSTANT`.

Answer (score 3):

This is called [monkey patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch), and it's fairly common although not preferred if there's another way to accomplish the same thing:

```
examplemod.config.CONSTANT = "Better value"
```

The issue is that you're relying on the internals of `examplemod` and `config` remaining the same, so this could break if either module changes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is enough or not, but did you try:

```
from example import config
config.CONSTANT = "A desirable value"
```

Make sure to do this before `examplemod` is imported. This should work because python caches imports so the `config` that you modified will be the same one that `examplemod` gets.