# Overriding a constant in a module

Tags: python, constants

I'm using the Python Pygatt module (https://github.com/ampledata/pygatt/tree/master/pygatt).

The classes.py file imports pygatt.constants which sets a few constants. I cannot figure out how to override these constants in my file foo.py I've tried:

```
import pygatt

pygat.classes.pygatt.constants.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_S = 8
```

But it doesn't work. I'm very confused and it's probably something dumb that I'm doing. Your help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possibly duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496089/how-can-i-override-a-constant-in-an-imported-python-module

Comment: I read that post and it didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
from pygatt.classes import pygatt
pygatt.constants.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_S = 8
```

Comment: When you say it does not work, what do you mean? did it throw an error or just did not pick up the change at runtime?

Comment: also note you have a typo in the example, the first "pygat" missing a "t"