# Python try except not using imported variable

Tags: python, global, try-except

Imported module, connection_status_message.py:

```
connection_status_message = "Not Connected"
```

Try Except file, connect_to_server.py:

```
from Server.connection_status_message import connection_status_message

def connect_to_server(host,user,password):
    try:
        connect(host,user,password)
    except NoConnection:
        connection_status_message = "Could not reach host..."
        return
...
```

The issue is the variable is trying to be made local. So I read up on the issue and saw how to reference a global variable:

```
def connect_to_server(host,user,password):
    try:
        connect(host,user,password)
    except NoConnection:
        global connection_status_message
        connection_status_message = "Could not reach host..."
        return
...
```

But now PyCharm is stating the import statement at the top is no longer being used.

How can I get this Try/Except to use the imported variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I override a constant in an imported Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496089/how-can-i-override-a-constant-in-an-imported-python-module)

Comment: Consider using a OOP approach, creating a class called `Connection` that handles the `connect()` and have an attribute of `connection_status_message`.

Comment: `pass` is a keyword. You can't use it as a variable name.

Comment: `pass` was just an abbreviation. I was unaware that it was a keyword so I changed it to `password` in the question to avoid confusion. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't replicate your issue, but if your `import` line is stored under a function, the variable is [`nonlocal` instead of `global`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example):

```
def connect_to_server(host,user,password):
    try:
        connect(host,user,password)
    except NoConnection:
        nonlocal connection_status_message
        connection_status_message = "Could not reach host..."
```

Another way is to not load the variable directly into your namespace so you have reference of where it came from to avoid local variables being created:

```
from Server import connection_status_message as csm
csm.connection_status_message

# "No Connection"

def func():    
    csm.connection_status_message = "Could not reach host..."

csm.connection_status_message

# "Could not reach host..."
```

You might also consider creating a class to handle all these as an object:

```
class Connection(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection_status_message = "No Connection"
        # TODO: initialize your class

    def connect(self, host, user, password):
        # TODO code connect criteria stuff here

    def connect_to_server(self, host, user, password):
        try:
            self.connect(host,user,password)
        except NoConnection:
            self.connection_status_message = "Could not reach host..."
            # ... return whatever ...#
```

Now you can do `from Server import Connection` and create a local `Connection` object to manipulate:

```
conn = Connection()
conn.connect_to_server(host, user, password)
```

This might be obvious, but in any case the value is only stored in memory during this execution.  The actual `connection_status_message.py` is never updated with this value.